# Bootstrap Accordion Targeting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have a bootstrap accordion that I need to target the class `.head-panel:first-child` and remove its `border-top`.

The code so far looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="firstPanel" class="panel-head container">
      <h4 class="dropHeader shadowStripBlue">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseQ1"></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically, there are a whole bunch of `div`s with the class `panel`.
I am needing to target the class `.panel-head` first child and remove a border-top on it.

So far in the CSS I have got something like this:

```
#accordion > .panel .panel-head:first-child {
    border: none;
}
```

At the moment it is just removing all the borders on all the divs, I only want it to remove the first-child.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: css is not enough. anyway try #accordion>.panel .panel-head:first-child{
    border-top: none;
}

Comment: Please provide an example of HTML with at least two items, and ideally a (working, minimal) jsFiddle.

Comment: There's a good chance your selector should be `#accordion .panel:first-child .panel-head`, but it's hard to guess without more details.

Comment: Don't understand... This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwnn58ru/) works. Is it what your looking for ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/R6EAW/3044/